# RestEasy - upload file (multipart/form-data) with cyrillic name

Tags: resteasy, multipartform-data, cyrillic

When I upload a file to the server, everything is fine. But if the name of the file contains cyrillic characters, on the server that filename appears with question marks.

I don't set any character encoding when I send request to the server.

I know that if you don't put any character encoding in the header when you make request, the default character encoding that RestEasy puts is us-ascii. I tried a couple of ways to change it:

- With new String(filename.getBytes("US-ASCII"), "UTF-8") - didn't work;
- I wrote ContainerRequestFilter, where I changed the ContentType of this request and I added charset=UTF-8 to the ContentType. It is set correctly but still doesn't work.

Could you please help! I would be very thankful!

Thanks!

Also posted on jboss.org [forum](https://developer.jboss.org/message/917662)

Comment: How are you running resteasy? as part of WildFly? if so, what version?

Comment: The version of RestEasy is 3.0.8. The version of wildfly is 8.1.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Don't change the Content-Type but use a `ContainerRequestFilter` to overwrite the default charset property:

```java
@Provider
public class CharsetFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
         requestContext.setProperty(InputPart.DEFAULT_CHARSET_PROPERTY, "UTF-8");
    }

}
```

Maybe you should check if there is a encoding provided and overwrite only if not.

Comment: Ok, I understood. Let me try. Thank you! I will share the results in a minutes.

Comment: It didn't work. I saw the property InputPart.DEFAULT_CHARSET_PROPERTY and the documentation above it says that your code should work. Strange that it is not working. Thanks anyway. I will continue trying.

Comment: Could you please check if [this example on github](https://github.com/lefloh/resteasy-fileupload) is working for you?

Comment: Thanks again lefloh! I saw the links but still don't have success. In my case the problem is that I can't set the header in the client (The UI developers can't). That's why I've tried with a filter and this is the only case that I can try. Still, no success.This is the code 

`@Provider

public class CharsetFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestContext.setProperty(InputPart.DEFAULT_CHARSET_PROPERTY, "UTF-8");
    }

} `

Comment: This should work so maybe there is another problem. Are you really getting UTF-8 or is your client sending content with a different encoding? You could try adding `<meta charset="utf-8" />` to the head of the document.

Comment: Yes, I've checked that. I have. Could that be RestEasy configuration or Wildfly configuration?

Comment: Sorry, basically this should work and I don't have more ideas.