# Filename encoding is wrong in MultipartFormDataInput with RestEasy and Wildfly 11

Tags: rest, encoding, wildfly, resteasy

My upload rest method works fine **unless the filename contains a special character**:

```
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
public Response uploadFile(MultipartFormDataInput input) {
    Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();
    List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get("file_upload");

    // Do Stuff...

}
```

The filename is **Test.png**, inputPart.getHeaders() = [Content-Disposition=form-data; name="tws_file"; filename="test.png",Content-Type=image/png]
--> **OK**

The filename is **Döner.png**, inputPart.getHeaders() = [Content-Disposition=form-data; name="tws_file"; filename="d��ner.png",Content-Type=image/png]
--> **Not OK**

**As you can see, the "ö" becomes "��".**

Things I've tried so far:

- Setting the **default encoding in my jboss_web.xml** to
  `<default-encoding>UTF-8</default-encoding>` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27974371/bad-special-character-encoding-with-resteasy))
- Changing my **@Consumes annotation** to `@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA+";charset=UTF-8");` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683677/how-to-set-encoding-in-resteasy-to-utf-8))
- Changing the encoding in a **container request filter** with `requestContext.setProperty(InputPart.DEFAULT_CHARSET_PROPERTY, "UTF-8");` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986897/resteasy-upload-file-multipart-form-data-with-cyrillic-name))

Nothing seems to work. Any ideas ? I am using Wildfly 11 and Resteasy-multipart-provider 3.0.24.Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been fixed in the latest version: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-1779

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the workaround of encoding the filename with a URI Encoder manually before sending it. On the other side, I decode it. That way, special characters are not a problem anymore.

Frontend in Angular:

```
encodeURI(fileName));
```

Backend in Java:

```
URLDecoder.decode(fileName, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: It worked fine, upgrade jboss is not an option for me...

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter` solved this issue for me (Wildfly 11.0.0, Resteasy provided):

```java
@Provider 
public class CharsetRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestContext.setProperty(InputPart.DEFAULT_CHARSET_PROPERTY, "UTF-8");
    }

}
```

Comment: is not working with Wildfly 15.0.0 and provided resteasy